# How to execute do_action in functions.asp

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a quick question with regards to my wordpress theme functions.asp file.

I have the below function that builds the main navigation menu for the site. In the second to last line I have a php do_action but it doesn't work? Can anyone tell me how I can get it to work in the function?

```
function alanbrandt_nav()
{
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        'menu'            => '', 
        'container'       => 'div', 
        'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container', 
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'menu', 
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
        )
    );
    echo "<li class='last'><form role='search' method='get' id='searchform' action='";
    echo "http://alanbrandt.com' class='' >";
    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<input type='text' value='' name='s' id='s' placeholder='Search' />";
    echo "<input type='submit' id='searchsubmit' value='Search' />";
        echo "</fieldset>";
    echo "</form></li></ul>";
    echo "<div id='language’>"do_action('zwt_lang_switcher', 'horizontal')"</div>";                            
        echo "<div class='cf'></div>";

}
```

Hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<div id='language’>" . do_action('zwt_lang_switcher', 'horizontal') . "</div>";
```

Try that. You forgot the concatenation operators. :)

Cheers!
=C=

Comment: Thanks Jay for correcting it and making it make sense. :)